# How do I get a variable value from a String in Java?

Tags: java, bukkit

So I am writing a debugger plugin for Minecraft bukkit and I was wondering how to get a public static variable value from a String. Here is some example code:

```
package example.package;

public class Ex {
 public static String foo = "bar";
}
```

If I were to give it the string "example.package.Ex.foo" it should return "bar", how do I do this?

Comment: Can you add some more context? How did you try specifying the string with bukkit? Did you specify quotes? If so, perhaps they should be removed?

Comment: Note that it is standard in Java to name constants all-caps, like `FOO`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- isn't it the all-caps is only for constants?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam You're correct, and I missed that this isn't declared `final`. OP, it is nearly always a problem to have static variables that are not final.

Comment: I think you're looking for **Reflection** yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using java 11(Reflection API) - *you can do this in older java versions too*

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var _this = new Main();
        _this.doJob();
    }
    
    void doJob() {
        var classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        try {
            var loaded = classLoader.loadClass("example.package.Ex");
            var obj = new Object();
            var field = loaded.getField("foo");
            System.out.println(field.get(obj));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**
A generic approach would be like this:

```
<T> T getFieldValueAtRuntime(String field) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    var classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    final var endIndex = field.lastIndexOf('.');
    final var fullClassName = field.substring(0, endIndex);
    final var fieldName = field.substring(endIndex + 1);
    var loadedClass = classLoader.loadClass(fullClassName);
    var obj = new Object();
    var fieldOfLoadedClass = loadedClass.getField(fieldName);
    return (T) fieldOfLoadedClass.get(obj);
}
-------------------------
try {
    String fieldValue = _this.getFieldValueAtRuntime("example.package.Ex.foo");
    System.out.println(fieldValue);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`example.package.Ex.foo` will return `bar` as you have mentioned. Static variables are owned by the class not by the instance so there will be only one copy of the variable exists and you dont need to create an instance.

If you want to access the variable in the same class simply use it by the name of the variable if you want to use it in another class you can use there are multiple ways.

1. By fully qualified name of the variable.

   ```
   package another.pack;

   public class AnotherClass {
      public void testVar(){
          String tempStr = example.package.Ex.foo;
      }
   }
   ```
2. Importing the class and using class.variable.

   ```
   package another.pack;

   import example.package.Ex;

   public class AnotherClass {
      public void testVar(){
          String tempStr = Ex.foo;
      }
   }
   ```
3. Static Import.

   ```
   package another.pack;

   import static example.package.Ex.foo;

   public class AnotherClass {
      public void testVar(){
          String tempStr = foo;
      }
   }
   ```

In all the above example the value of the `tempStr` will be `"bar"`

**Since there will be only one copy of the variable exits you have to be careful if the variable is changed in one place it will affect all the place.**

If you want a constant use `final` keyword when declaring the variable

```java
package example.package;

public class Ex {
 public static final String FOO = "bar";
}
```

> Note: the convention is to use upper case for constants.

Comment: Yes, but I want to get it from a String